# Deploying app, troubles to reffer to datasets. Streamlit

Tags: deployment, streamlit

Hello i have one more problem with deploying my app by Streamlit. It works localy but when I want to upload it on git hub it doesnt work..Have no idea whats wrong. It seems that there is problem with path to the file:

```
"File "/app/streamlit/bobrza.py", line 14, in <module>
    bobrza_locations = pd.read_csv(location)"
```

Here is link to my github repo. Will be very very grateful for help. Thank in advance.

https://github.com/Bordonous/streamlit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you are hard coding the path of the bobrza1.csv and route.csv to the path on your computer so when running the code on a different environment the path in not legal.

The solution is to make location independent from running environment, for this we will use the following:

1. _*_*file_*_* variable - the path to the current python module (the .py file).
2. os.path.dirname() - a function to get directory name from path.
3. os.path.abspath() - a function to get a normalized absolutized version of path.
4. os.path.join() - a function to join one or more path components.

Now you need to change your location and location2 variables in the code to the following:

```
# get the absolute path to the directory contain the .csv file
dir_name = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# join the bobrza1.csv to directory to get file path
location = os.path.join(dir_name, 'bobrza1.csv')

# join the route.csv to directory to get file path
location2 = os.path.join(dir_name, 'route.csv')
```

Resulting in an independent path of the bobrza1.csv and route.csv.

Comment: thanks for help mate, im really grateful